# what's the correct way of using dotnet commands in gitlab-ci pipeline?

Tags: .net, gitlab-ci

I'm building a dotnet pipeline in gitlab-ci for a .net repo where the porpuse is publishing some projects and package one of them, however it's my first time working with dotnet and I have some doubts related to how run the commands.

Mainly my doubt is related with using artifacts an dependencies with other jobs and stages. For example, if I have a build stage where I use the dotnet restore and dotnet build commands and I save the output of the build command as artifacts and then I have another three stages and jobs for testing, publishing and packagin and for these new jobs I have the artifacts of the before job as dependency...I don't need to use dotnet restore and dotnet build again in this new jobs right? And if this is correct, Do I just need to specify in the commands the flag --no-restore and --no-build and the command will know in what directory the artifacts are for making the publish or tests? Or should I specify where those artifacts are?

Thanks in advance and sorry for many text.

Hope someone can help me :)